# Grothendieck group of local affine- surfaces with rational singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, sheaf-cohomology, derived-functors, algebraic-k-theory

Let $(R, \mathfrak m)$ be an excellent, normal, local  domain of dimension $2$ containing an algebraically closed field $k=R/\mathfrak m$. Let $ \pi: Y \to X=\operatorname {Spec}(R)$ be a resolution of singularities  (which exists by a Theorem of Lipman) and also assume $H^1(Y, \mathcal O_Y)=0$ i.e. $X$ has geometric genus zero (this doesn't depend on the choice of resolution). One Algebraic characterization of the vanishing of this sheaf Cohomology in this context is that $IJ$ is an integrally closed ideal for every integrally closed ideals $I$ and $J$ of $R$ 
(See Theorem 1 of https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01233425)

Let $G_0(R)$ be the Grothendieck group of the abelian category of finitely generated $R$-modules.

Then, is it true that $G_0(R)\otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Q$ is a finite dimensional $\mathbb Q$-vector space ?

Comment: Do you know what $G_{0}(R)$ of any local ring is?

Comment: The ring described is a field no?

Comment: @Zeek: the Grothendieck group of a local ring can be possibly anything (may or may not have torsion ...) ... and do note that I'm not talking about the $K_0$-group ... for example, for Artinian local rings, it is $\mathbb Z$ but for say $\mathbb R[[x,y]]/(x^2+y^2)$, it is $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ ...

Comment: @metalspringpro: I'm not sure ... why do you think that ?

Comment: @Zeek: and very generally, $G_0(R)$ is generated by $[R/P]$ as $P$ runs over all prime ideals ...

Comment: @Zeek: actually, $\mathbb R[[x,y]]/(x^2+y^2)$ being the completion of $\mathbb R[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$, I'm not sure what the Grothendieck group is, but for $\mathbb R[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$, the Grothendieck group is $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, so for a local example take $\mathbb R[x,y]_{(x,y)}/(x^2+y^2)$ , since the Grothendieck group of a standard graded Algebra over a field doesn't change after localizing at the homogeneous maximal ideal, as can be seen from proof of (ii) of Theorem 1.5 of https://doi.org/10.1016/S0021-8693(02)00082-0 ... (cont'd.)

Comment: @Zeek: (cont'd from previous) ... however, the Grothendieck group of a local ring can behave very badly under completion , for example see https://mathscinet.ams.org/leavingmsn?url=https://doi.org/10.1307/mmj/1220879404 ... this among other things tells you how the subtle the Grothendieck group of a local ring is ...

Comment: I have heard Grothendieck group to be $K_{0}(R)$ (which is obviously $\mathbb{Z}$ for local rings) so thought you might be using a different notation for that. I'm not so familiar with the group $G_{0}(R)$. Apologies

Comment: @Zeek: I did mention that let $G_0(R)$ be the Grothendieck group of the abelian category of finitely generated modules (and did NOT say that it was the Grothendieck group of the exact category of finitely generated Projective modules) ... but apology accepted ...

Comment: @Loius A finitely generated k-algebra is Jacobson and you also assume it is local, so it is Artinian. You also assume is it normal, so it is a field.

Comment: @metalspringpro: I guess you're right ... I didn't want to use the intricate definition of pseudo-rationality in general, so I thought assuming it is a variety but varieties can't be local unless they are field ... I'll edit the question to make appropriate changes ...